How do I combine multiple pairs of images?
The file names look like this:

363-main.jpg
363-overlay.png
364-main.jpg
365-main.jpg
365-overlay.png
366-main.jpg
366-overlay.png
367-main.jpg
368-main.jpg

So there are many .jpgs that do not have a matching .png overlay that will need to be skipped. All overlays are unique to the main image.
This is what I tried (pulled from here: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=32333)
magick *-main.jpg -extent %[fx:s.w*2] null: *-overlay.png -gravity east -layers composite _%03d_out.png

And this is the error I get:
no matches found: %[fx:s.w*2]

Can anyone provide any clarity on why I'm getting this error and how I can fix this? Thank you.

Try putting quotes around %[fx:s.w*2]

@fmw42 This worked, thank you! However, the png overlay is to the left of the main image now. I also tried using "Center" instead of "east", but the png is only overlapped halfway.

Your PNGs may have a virtual convas.  So after *-overlay.png add +repage.  See if that helps.

I tried this from the Windows Command Prompt and it worked as you would expect, combining the sources and generating output.  If you're running magick from a *nix shell, it's possible that it is parsing %[fx:s.w*2] as a filename.  I'm sorry I can't be of more assistance, I've only ever used it on Windows.
Try executing it as follows:
magick "*-main.jpg" -extent %[fx:s.w*2] null: "*-overlay.png" -gravity east -layers composite _%03d_out.png

I hope this helps.
